# Pyspark: List subfolders names in AWS S3 folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Main folder:
s3_path = "s3a://prices/xml_inputs/stores/"

My try:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv()

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

# Create the SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("price-xml-s3") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.12.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Set S3 configuration
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
                                                  "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider,com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

# Define the S3 path to the main folder
s3_path = "s3a://prices/xml_inputs/stores/"

# Get the FileSystem object
fs = SparkContext.getOrCreate()._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

# List the subfolders
subfolders = [path.toString() for path in fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(s3_path)) if path.isDirectory()]

# Print the subfolder names
for subfolder in subfolders:
    print(subfolder)
```

In output I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 36, in <module>
    subfolders = [path.toString() for path in fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(s3_path)) if path.isDirectory()]
: Wrong FS: s3a://prices/xml_inputs/stores, expected: file:///
```

When I try to export a single file the path is OK but when I try to list subfolders I get an error.

Comment: Why not use boto3 for this?

Comment: I know that with Python boto3 is simple, but I need to use only PySpark.

Comment: But why needlessly invoke JVM code? PySpark is still running "in a Python environment" where you can use boto3